# database - storing timetables in one row for each week day or in one single row for all week days?

Tags: mysql, database, timetable

In my database I manage timetables like this:

**timetables** table
**id** - int (primary key)
**start_time** - int (minutes)
**end_time** - int (minutes)
**week_day** - int (day number: 1 for Monday, 7 for Sunday)

the **id** field is foreign key in other tables
since if a timetable is repeated for all days of the week and I have to store 7 rows in timetables and each other table with the foreign key
what about instead storing the week_day fields as an int of up to 7 digits (1234567) and query it as a string:

```
... WHERE week_day LIKE '%3%' /*wednesday*/
```

are there any cons in doing this?

**UPDATE**
my intention is to change **timetables** table
from:

```
id  shop_id start_time  end_time    week_day (int)
1   1       480         720         1           /*shop1 08:00 - 12:00 monday*/
2   1       480         720         2           /*shop1 08:00 - 12:00 tuesday*/
3   1       480         720         3           /*shop1 08:00 - 12:00 wednesday*/
4   1       900         1140        7           /*shop1 15:00 - 19:00 sunday*/
```

into:

```
id  shop_id start_time  end_time    week_day (int)
1   1       480         720         123         /*shop1 08:00 - 12:00 monday,tuesday,wednesday*/
2   1       900         1140        7           /*shop1 15:00 - 19:00 sunday*/
```

example query:

```
SELECT * FROM timetables WHERE shop_id=1 AND week_day LIKE '%3%'
```

**OTHER POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

```
id  shop_id start_time  end_time    monday  tuesday wednesday   thursday    friday  saturday    sunday
1   1       480         720         1       1       1           NULL        NULL    NULL        NULL    /*shop1 08:00 - 12:00 monday,tuesday,wednesday*/
2   1       900         1140        NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL        NULL    NULL        1       /*shop1 15:00 - 19:00 sunday*/
```

Comment: write the queries that retrieve this data for both approaches and hopefully an answer will be obvious.

Comment: What is `start_time` and `end_time` - And how would you "merge" 7 of them into a single row?

Comment: @danblack and @PaulSpiegel `start_time` and `end_time` are the same for each timetable e.g. 08:00 (480 minutes) and 12:00 (720 minutes) so instead of repeating them for each week day I'd concat them in a single row

Comment: IMHO both designs look bad. And it's still not clear, what you are storing there.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel please see edit, I'm storing shop timetables, how would you do?

Comment: Your statements (in question and comments) are not consistent. You write `start_time/end_time` are always the same, but in the sample data it's not.

Comment: Most drawbacks of the second approach are descibed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: @PaulSpiegel sorry I meant `start_time/end_time` are always the same **for each timetable** which can be repeated for x days of the week, regarding those drawbacks the `INSERT INTO timetables` query is managed by a php script which always writes a maximum of 7 digits from 1 to 7, anyway creating one BIT(1)NULL field for each of the 7 week days would be a better approach?

Comment: If in doubt - use the most normalized design. Do you have any troubles with the current design?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel the only trouble I see in the current design is the redundancy of fields `start_time/end_time` and up to 6 more rows for timetables in all days of the week and storing the list I could keep 1 field instead of 7